# How to setup that Unit tests runs whenever running Archive on an app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Is it possible to make sure the tests are run whenever anyone archives an app in Xcode?

[image]

For example in this pre-action when i run Archive you could set so that the Test debug scheme is run. Is this possible in a hidden setting or with a script somehow?